# Filter a dictionary based on a constraint on the keys in a Pythonic way

Tags: python, dictionary

Given a dictionary, I would like to get a new dictionary that is a subset of the original dictionary by checking which keys satisfy a specific constraint. For example, for a dictionary with string keys, filter to keys that start with a certain substring.

```
» d = {'Apple': 1, 'Banana': 9, 'Carrot': 6, 'Baboon': 3, 'Duck': 8, 'Baby': 2}
» print slice(d, 'Ba')
{'Banana': 9, 'Baby': 2, 'Baboon': 3}
```

This is fairly simple to do with a function:

```
def slice(sourcedict, string):
    newdict = {}
    for key in sourcedict.keys():
        if key.startswith(string):
            newdict[key] = sourcedict[key]
    return newdict
```

But surely there is a nicer, cleverer, or more "readable" solution? Could a generator help here? (I never have enough opportunities to use those).

Comment: Don't obscure python code just because it is possible. The whole idea of python is readability. If you just need obscure power, use Perl.

Comment: Also see http://pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-custom-objects-classes-in-python/, you can customize `__getitem__` in your own type/subclass of dict.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

How about this:

in python 2.x :

```
def slicedict(d, s):
    return {k:v for k,v in d.iteritems() if k.startswith(s)}
```

In python 3.x :

```
def slicedict(d, s):
    return {k:v for k,v in d.items() if k.startswith(s)}
```

Comment: Don't shadow the `slice` built-in (even though almost no one uses it).

Comment: That dict comprehension is delicious. And I had no idea `slice` was a builtin, wtf?

Comment: @Ignacio: When you're in a tiny, local function, it really isn't always worth worrying about stepping on builtins--there are too many of them, with far too common names.  Better just to worry about it for nontrivial functions (if that) and globals.  Builtins aren't keywords, after all.

Comment: No dictionary comprehension way `dict((k, v) for k,v in d.iteritems() if k.startswith(s))`

Comment: in 2017: python can comprehension a dict purely using `in`: `{k:d[k] for k in d if k.startswith(s)}`, no more need to invoke a function call.

Answer (score 9):

In functional style:

`dict(filter(lambda item: item[0].startswith(string),sourcedict.iteritems()))`

Comment: In Python, functional style is usually just what you don't want.

Comment: Eh? The dict-comprehension approach certainly falls under my definition of "functional style".

Answer (score 3):

In [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) use `items()` instead:

```
def slicedict(d, s):
    return {k:v for k,v in d.items() if k.startswith(s)}
```