# Splitting a python dict from a certain key

Tags: python, dictionary, slice

I'm trying to split a dict from a certain point in the dict. It seemed like doing a simple `items_dict[3:]` would work but it did not work.

```
items_dict = {
    "Cannon barrels":10,
    "Cannon furnace":12,
    "Candle":36,
    "Bronze arrowheads":39,
    "Iron arrowheads":40,
    "Steel arrowheads":41,
    "Mithril arrowheads":42,
    "Adamant arrowheads":4
}
print items_dict[3:] # Nope, this won't work
print items_dict["Candle"] # This will of course, but only returns the Candle's number
```

I only figured out how [to slice a dictionary by keys that start with a certain string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558983/slicing-a-dictionary-by-keys-that-start-with-a-certain-string), but I just want to know how to slice a dictionary similar to a list.

Comment: Looks like maybe you should rethink your datastructures. I don't think it's a good idea to use an OrderedDict here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to split after n keys - no guarantee over the order.

```
n=3
d1 = {key: value for i, (key, value) in enumerate(d.items()) if i < n}
d2 = {key: value for i, (key, value) in enumerate(d.items()) if i >= n}
```

Comment: `viewitems` is python2.7.  `items` will work on python2 or python3.

Comment: You could also do something like:  `{k:d[k] for k in islice(d,...)}`

Comment: Using an OrderedDict as suggested in an answer below and in the comment above, this worked just as needed!

Comment: @mgilson, islice is much better, but with an `iter(d)` so you save looping over stuff multiple times.

Comment: @gnibbler -- Sorry, you're going to need to walk me through this one a bit more.  How does using `islice` cause you to loop multiple times?

Comment: @mgilson, if you do `islice(d, n)` followed by `islice(d, n, None)` you will be iterating over the first `n` of `d` twice.

Comment: @gnibbler -- Oh, I got ya.  You mean to split the list into 2 parts.  In that case I suppose it becomes `iterd = iter(d); {k:d[k] for k in islice(iterd,n)}; {k:d[k] for k in iterd}`

Answer (score 4):

Dictionaries don't have order, so you can't split it from a certain point.  Looking at the dictionary you have there, you can't know ahead of time what the first element will be.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a dictionary where the keys are stored in order, use `collections.OrderedDict`

http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Answer (score 1):

```
items = [
    ("Cannon barrels",10),
    ("Cannon furnace",12),
    ("Candle",36),
    ....
   ]

items_dict = dict(items)

items_3_dict = dict(items[3:])
```

doesnt exactly answer your question (see @mgilson answer) , but provides a path forward

Answer (score 1):

```
ditems = items_dict.items()
d1, d2 = dict(ditems[:3]), dict(ditems[3:])

print(d1)
print(d2)
{'Iron arrowheads': 40, 'Adamant arrowheads': 4, 'Mithril arrowheads': 42}
{'Candle': 36, 'Cannon barrels': 10, 'Steel arrowheads': 41, 'Cannon furnace': 12, 'Bronze arrowheads': 39}
```

Or creating a function to split an iterable about an `n`-th value

```
from itertools import islice

def split(iterable,point): 
    return islice(iterable,None,point), islice(iterable,point,None)

d1, d2 = (dict(segment) for segment in split(items_dict.items(),3))
```

This will *split* it about the third entry.

Comment: no it wont ... a dict has no concept of "third entry"  ... it will create a dict with 3 of the items and another dict with the rest ... but there is no concept of "third entry"

Comment: @JoranBeasley (yes it's unorderded) but it still has N (k,v) pairs which I meant by entry, so even though the 3rd pair is indeterminate it still has a third pair.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a custom class (example only - slicing only works for `[1:4]` syntax, and `dict[missing_key]` returns None instead of throwing an exception):

```
>>> class SliceDict(collections.OrderedDict):
...     def __getitem__(self, val):
...         if isinstance(val, slice):
...             return {key: value for i, (key, value) in enumerate(d.items()) if val.start < i < val.stop}
...         else:
...             return self.get(val)
```

Now we can add your items dict:

```
>>> d = SliceDict(items_dict)
SliceDict([('Adamant arrowheads', 4), ('Mithril arrowheads', 42), ('Iron arrowheads', 40), ('Candle', 36), ('Cannon barrels', 10), ('Steel arrowheads', 41), ('Cannon furnace', 12), ('Bronze arrowheads', 39)])
>>> d[1:5]
{'Candle': 36, 'Cannon barrels': 10, 'Iron arrowheads': 40}
>>> d['Candle']
36
```